# binder1st,binder2nd difference

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

what is difference between binder1st and binder2nd functions
like->

```
     binder1st < equal_to<int> > equal_to_10 (equal_to<int>(),10);
     int numbers[] = {10,20,30,40,50,10};
     int cx;
     cx = count_if (numbers,numbers+6,equal_to_10);
```

and

```
binder2nd < equal_to<int> > equal_to_10 (equal_to<int>(),10);
  int numbers[] = {10,20,30,40,50,10};
  int cx;
  cx = count_if (numbers,numbers+6,equal_to_10);
```

what does binding to 1st argument and second argument mean?

Someone can take other example and explain

Comment: Don't ask two distinct questions in one post.

Comment: ok I will move the second question to a separate thread tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

In one case you are binding the 1st argument, and in the other case, the 2nd.  So it's the difference between:

```
equal_to<>(30, 10)

equal_to<>(10, 30)
```

Which because equality is commutative, means exactly the same thing.  If you were using `less<>` for example, it would matter, and your example would be more clear.